# C variadic wrapper

Tags: c, wrapper, variadic

To output formatted debug output, I've written a wrapper for `vsfprint`. Now, I wanted to allocate exactly enough memory for the output buffer, instead of just claiming a random high buffer size (it's a small embedded platform (ESP8266)). For that I iterate through the variable arguments until a NULL is found.

This works fine, provided that I don't forget to add a `(char *)NULL` parameter to every call. So, I thought, let create another wrapper, a function that just relays all arguments and adds a `(char *) NULL` parameter:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // malloc

void write_log(const char *format, ...) {

  char* buffdyn;
  va_list args;

  //  CALC. MEMORY
  size_t len;
  char *p;

  if(format == NULL)
    return;

  len = strlen(format);

  va_start(args, format);

  while((p = va_arg(args, char *)) != NULL)
    len += strlen(p);

  va_end(args);
  // END CALC. MEMORY

  // ALLOCATE MEMORY
  buffdyn = malloc(len + 1);    /* +1 for trailing \0 */
  if(buffdyn == NULL) {
    printf("Not enough memory to process message.");
    return;
  }

  va_start(args, format);
  //vsnprintf = Write formatted data from variable argument list to sized buffer
  vsnprintf(buffdyn, len, format, args);
  va_end(args);

  printf("%s\r\n",buffdyn);
  free(buffdyn);
}

void write_log_wrapper(const char *format, ...) {

  va_list arg;

  va_start(arg, format);
  write_log(format,arg,(char *)NULL);
  va_end(arg);
}


int main()
{
    const char* sDeviceName = "TEST123";
    const char* sFiller1 = "12345678";

    write_log_wrapper("Welcome to %s%s", sDeviceName,sFiller1);
    write_log("Welcome to %s%s", sDeviceName,sFiller1, (char *)NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Calling the `write_log()` function directly works fine (if you don't forget the NULL parameter). Calling the `write_log_wrapper()` function will only display the first paramter, and then adds a "(nu" (garbage?) to the output.

What am I doing wrong? Is this a good way to approach what I'm aiming to do in the first place?

Thanks.

Comment: If you intend to write it to `stdout`, why don't you simply use `vprintf`? The same follows if you want to write to a file (use `vfprintf`). Then there is no buffer allocation in your code at all and you don't have to deal with figuring out how many arguments or how big of a buffer.

Comment: You're ignoring the possibility that one of the arguments passed isn't a NUL-terminated string passed via a `char *`.  What if you get an `int`, or a `double`?

Comment: ... or a NULL with %p

Comment: Reason why is, and you can't see that from this simplified example, is that the function does more than simply spit out the buffer.  It also adds a timestamp, and, via an extra parameter, adds some ANSI coloring depending on that parameter ;-). But I wanted to keep the example simple ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To determine how big a buffer is needed to hold the output string, you need to **fully parse the entire format string and actually expand the arguments**.

You can either do it yourself, duplicating all the processing of `printf()` and its ilk and hoping to not make any mistakes, or you can use `vsnprintf()` - first to determine the size, and then to actually expand the inputs to one output string.

```
#define FIXED_SIZE 64

void write_log(const char *format, ...)
{
    // set up a fixed-size buffer and a pointer to it
    char fixedSizeBuffer[ FIXED_SIZE ];
    char *outputBuffer = fixedSizeBuffer;

    // no dynamic buffer yet
    char *dynamicBuffer = NULL;

    // get the variable args
    va_list args1;
    va_start( args1, format );

    // need to copy the args even though we won't know if we
    // need them until after we use the first set
    va_list args2;
    va_copy( args2, args1 );

    // have to call vsnprintf at least once - might as well use a small
    // fixed-size buffer just in case the final string fits in it
    int len = vsnprintf( fixedSizeBuffer, sizeof( fixedSizeBuffer ), format, args1 );
    va_end( args1 );

    // it didn't fit - get a dynamic buffer, expand the string, and
    // point the outputBuffer pointer at the dynamic buffer so later
    // processing uses the right string
    if ( len > sizeof( fixedSizeBuffer  ) )
    {
        dynamicBuffer = malloc( len + 1 );
        vsnprintf( dynamicBuffer, len + 1, format, args2 );
        outputBuffer = dynamicBuffer;
    }

    va_end( args2 );

    // do something with outputBuffer

    free( dynamicBuffer );
    return;
}
```

Comment: good idea but there are systems where you must not use `args` twice (e.g. linux on IBM Z series) so you should add a `va_copy()`

Comment: A very solid solution, tested it and it works out of the box :D.

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

Passing a `va_list arg`

```
write_log(format, arg, (char *)NULL);
```

is not the same as passing several `char*`

```
write_log("Welcome to %s%s", sDeviceName, sFiller1, (char *)NULL);
```

---

You won't get around to pass a sentinel marking the end of the parameters passed, that is a `(char*) NULL` or whatever you decide to use.

---

Alternatives would be to

- pass the number of arguments explicitly, perhaps as 2nd parameter
- parse the format string for conversion specifiers, in fact mimicking what `printf` does.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just to ensure that all calls receive a setinel at the end, use a macro:

```
#define WRITE_LOG(...) write_log(__VA_ARGS__, (char*)0)
```

This ensures that there is always an extra `0` at the end.

Also be careful with `NULL`. It is underspecified in the C standard to what expressions this resolves. Common cases are `0` and `(void*)0`. So on 64bit architectures these may have different width (32 bit for the first, 64 bit for the second). It can be deadly for a variadic function to receive the wrong width here. Therefore I used `(char*)0` which is the type that your function seems to expect. (But `(void*)0` would also do in this special case.)

Comment: Given that the target platform is "a small embedded platform", I'd recommend the OP verify that `(char*)0` is in fact a `NULL` pointer for the compiler being used before using at as such.  I don't think `(char*)0` was mandated to be a valid `NULL` pointer until C11.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, you probably mean null pointer and not `NULL` pointer. `(char*)0` is not a "null pointer constant" in the sense of the standard, here you would in effect need `(void*)0`. But for the case at hand this is irrelevant, it is a null pointer of the right type as the program expects.

Comment: It sometimes works, sometimes crashes.. looks like to depend on the number of arguments.. Can't really understand why yet.